# To whom does his refers to in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111161/synopsis)

> *One day Red tells Tommy about Andy's case. Tommy is visibly upset at hearing Andy's story and tells Andy and Red that he had a cellmate in another prison who boasted about killing a man who was a pro golfer at the country club he worked at, along with **his lover**.*

In this above sentence, To whom does his refers to?

Comment: The fact that you think you have quoted enough to answer the question is a strong indicator that "his" refers to the pro golfer, since nobody else is mentioned who it could refer to.

Comment: @ThePhoton Oops, sorry, I missed the OP's link. _When I consider how my light is spent..._

Comment: Who do you think *his* refers to?

Comment: @AlanCarmack **His lover** in this quotation refers to **the lover of the pro golfer murdered by the cellmate of the character called "Tommy."**

Comment: Considering typical motives for murder it's pretty clearly implied we're taking about the pro golfer. In other contexts there could be more potential for ambiguity but I highly doubt this was meant any other way.

Answer (score 1):

"His" refers to the pro golfer.

In your sentence

> killing a man who was a pro golfer at the country club he worked at, along with his lover.

a comma seems to be missing

> killing a man, who was a pro golfer at the country club he worked at, along with his lover.

which would give you (leaving out the subordinate clause)

> killing a man along with his lover.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, simplify that -

> One day Red tells Tommy about Andy's case. Tommy is visibly upset at hearing Andy's story...
>
> *Tommy* tells Andy and Red that he (Tommy) had a cellmate in *another prison*
>
> the cellmate boasted about killing a man (call this man Mike)
>
> Mike was a pro golfer at the country club he (Tommy) worked at, along with his (Mike's) lover.